# Advice for selecting proper ROM for my old device

Tags: updates

I have quite old device PocketBook SURFpad 3 (10,1")([specs](https://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=e9c1-0608-ffff-ffffa57c34c8)). And I want to update it, to more modern android version. Unfortunately, I have not done it before, so I would like to ask about an advice. The first step is selecting ROM with right architecture(ARMv7/6...). What are the criterias for selecting of ROM? Should i pay attention only on ARMv7 or specific processor MT8382.

I would be very appreciate for any advices.

Comment: there is no ROM for your device